# Zend Router various URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I would like to achieve something like this with ZF router. (`'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'`)

```
//Show product details   
'http://mydomain.com/en/products/category-1/subcategory-3/product-name.htm'

//List products in subcategory-3
'http://mydomain.com/en/products/category-1/subcategory-3.htm'

//List products in category-1
'http://mydomain.com/en/products/category-1.htm'

//List products in all categories
'http://mydomain.com/en/products.htm'
```

Do I have to specify each possibility as separate route? Or is there better solution? (Using `Route_Regex`?)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a route to approximate that by having empty defaults like so:

```
resources.router.routes.products.route = ":lang/products/:category/:subcategory/:product"
resources.router.routes.products.defaults.category=""  
resources.router.routes.products.defaults.subcategory=""       
resources.router.routes.products.defaults.product=""
resources.router.routes.products.defaults.controller="products"
resources.router.routes.products.defaults.action="index"
```

That route isn't going to handle your `.htm` extension on `/en/products.htm`, and the category/subcategory/product might have a `.htm` appended to their values.   It is probably easier to handle stripping the `.htm` from the request with a little .htaccess `RewriteRule` magic rather than working around it with basic Zend_Router)

```
 RewriteRule /([^/]+)/products(.*)\.htm /$1/products$2
```

The alternative would be to use a [Custom or Regular Expression route](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/16/routing-and-complex-urls-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: Thanks! The idea of stripping the `.htm` part seems to be an easy and clean solution. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: I just found that the solution with mod_rewrite does not work, because the Zend_Router only sees the original URI, not the rewritten. The only way is to use [R]edirect flag, but it has no sense in this case. :-(